# How can I debug the operator.c file using gdb

Tags: gdb

I have divided my c code in three parts main.c operator.c and header.h I complie but but not able to debug the operator.c can some one help with this

Comment: Maybe you didn't compile it with `-g` option?

Comment: ya I got it. just add the function name as break point.